# I need to call custom package/class controller actions remotely. Possible?

Tags: api, soap-api, remote-action

We have several custom packages (SCM, Conga, FF). I've only ever used SOQL triggers for remote API use. We have a situation where a package action triggers several events across multiple packages. The "button action" inside VisualForce/SF does this by design. But now we need to trigger this button (persay) remotely. So here're my questions:

1. How do I find the publicly explosed (API) methods in a package class?
2. How can I find the methods/functions associated with a button?

Thanks a lot for any guidance on these sort of fundamentals. We're not SF experts, we're merely remoting in via SOAP to sync some platforms. So I just don't know where/how to approach source code inspection to work with poorly documented 3rd party packages. Thanks again!

Comment: Update: I've located the Apex Class by the name of the Controller in the VisualForce button designer. It has a list of methods! Hopefully I'm on to something. The method in question is:

System.PageReference allocate()

But that's all it says. Am I on the right track?

Assuming I load the wsdl into SOAP for this Apex class....

How can I determine what params/properties are required?

Comment: You can only access global classes and methods inside of a managed package. Public methods are not accessible to you outside of the package.

Comment: That's hopeful, thank you. It does indeed appear to be a global class according to the detail page.

Answer (score 2):

If you have located a global Apex class within the managed package with the required global method and you are working via the SOAP API then anonymous Apex would be a good option.

Using the [executeAnonymous](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_tooling/Content/intro_soap_overview.htm) method in either the Tooling or [Apex APIs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=sforce_api_calls_executeanonymous.htm%7CStartTopic=Content%2Fsforce_api_calls_executeanonymous.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp) you can invoke the global method.

You call the method with a string containing the Apex to execute the method.

E.g. using some rough C#. You will need to replace *PackageNamespace* and *PackageClass* as required. The developer console would be a good place to test out the anonymous Apex first before writing the code against the SOAP API.

```
string anonApex = @"
    PackageNamespace.PackageClass pc = new PackageNamespace.PackageClass();
    PageReference pr = pc.allocate();
    System.debug(LoggingLevel.Error, pr);";

ToolingService toolingService = // create an instance of the ToolingService ...
ExecuteAnonymousResult result = toolingService.executeAnonymous(anonApex);
```

The trick will be if you want to extract some data from the resulting PageReference. There are two approaches I know of. [Subvert an exception to return the required data](http://codefriar.wordpress.com/2014/10/30/eval-in-apex-secure-dynamic-code-evaluation-on-the-salesforce1-platform/) or [capture and process the resulting Apex Debug log](http://www.fishofprey.com/2014/11/adding-eval-support-to-apex.html).